# Difference in reading from file in unix

Tags: bash, unix

I have the file content as

```
bash-4.4$ cat b.txt                                                                                                                       
unix unix                                                                                                                                 
unix                                                                                                                                      
unix unix unix                                                                                                                            
linux                                                                                                                                     
linux linux
```

The below script reading the content of the file one with for loop and another with while loop . But both are printing the content in two different ways. What is the reason ?

```
#/usr/bin/bash                                                                                                                            

echo "for loop approach"                                                                                                                  
for i in $(cat b.txt)                                                                                                                     
do                                                                                                                                        
echo $i                                                                                                                                   
done                                                                                                                                      

echo ""                                                                                                                                   
echo "while approach"                                                                                                                     
cat b.txt | while read line                                                                                                               
do                                                                                                                                        
echo $line                                                                                                                                
done       

bash-4.4$ bash aa.bash                                                                                                                    
for loop approach                                                                                                                         
unix                                                                                                                                      
unix                                                                                                                                      
unix                                                                                                                                      
unix                                                                                                                                      
unix                                                                                                                                      
unix                                                                                                                                      
linux                                                                                                                                     
linux                                                                                                                                     
linux                                                                                                                                     

while approach                                                                                                                            
unix unix                                                                                                                                 
unix                                                                                                                                      
unix unix unix                                                                                                                            
linux                                                                                                                                     
linux linux
```

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls :- read everything on this page as many times as possible

Answer (score 4):

In shell, [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) occurs on the characters of `IFS` variables: space, tab, and newline by default.

In your `for` approach, you have not quoted the command substitution, `$(cat b.txt)`, hence word splitting (and [pathname expansion](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0080.php)) is being triggered resulting in words separated by those characters of `IFS` as separate entities in the output.

With the `while` approach, `read` reads each whole line (up to `\n`), so you're getting the whole lines in the output.

Using a `for` loop with command substitution is *always* the wrong approach while reading from a file line by line. Use a `while` loop with `read` instead.